# Android navigation drawer selected item default background?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image: screenshot]

I use buildToolsVersion "24.0.2".
I have such a problem. How do I solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i copied from sample navigation drawer app. I have no editing. The selected drawer item is completely painted with accent color. please click screenshot up. Please click the above screenshots

Comment: Add some alpha to your accent color, quick fix. Or create a new theme for the navigation drawer to use, real fix.

Comment: thanks but nothing has changed